# Join two dataframes in pyspark by one column

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have a two dataframes that I need to join by one column and take just rows from the first dataframe if that id is contained in the same column of second dataframe:

df1:

```
  id    a     b
  2     1     1
  3    0.5    1
  4     1     2
  5     2     1
```

df2:

```
 id      c    d
  2      fs   a
  5      fa   f
```

Desired output:

```
df:
  id   a   b
   2   1   1
   5   2   1
```

I have tried with df1.join(df2("id"),"left"), but gives me error :'Dataframe' object is not callable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`df2("id")` is not a valid python syntax for selecting columns, you'd either need `df2[["id"]]` or use `select` `df2.select("id")`; For your example, you can do:

```
df1.join(df2.select("id"), "id").show()

+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|
+---+---+---+
|  5|2.0|  1|
|  2|1.0|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

or:

```
df1.join(df2[["id"]], "id").show()
+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|
+---+---+---+
|  5|2.0|  1|
|  2|1.0|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Sorry, I have copied my syntaxt, but made another dataframes here. Imsi is and ID

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check if `id` exists in `df2` and does not need any column in your output from df2 then `isin()` is more efficient solution (This is similar to `EXISTS` and `IN` in SQL).

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(2,1,1) ,(3,5,1,),(4,1,2),(5,2,1)], "id: Int, a : Int , b : Int")

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(2,'fs','a') ,(5,'fa','f')], ['id','c','d'])
```

Create df2.id as list and pass it to df1 under `isin()`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df2_list = df2.select('id').rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()

df1.where(col('id').isin(df2_list)).show()

#+---+---+---+
#| id|  a|  b|
#+---+---+---+
#|  2|  1|  1|
#|  5|  2|  1|
#+---+---+---+
```

It is reccomended to use `isin()` IF -

- You don't need to return data from the refrence dataframe/table
- You have duplicates in the refrence dataframe/table (JOIN can cause   duplicate rows if values are repeated)
- You just want to check existence of particular value